# How does a protein molecule enter a cell through the cell membrane?

Tags: proteins, cell-membrane

I can't find a good explanation as to how a whole protein molecule **enters** a cell membrane. Is it through endocytotic vesicles, with the help of ATP? How does this occur?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you asking about translocation, or about folded proteins passing through membranes?

Comment: Learning about both would be great!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_targeting#Protein_translocation) has some information on translocation, and follow that up with their article on the translocon (the machinery that threads nascent peptides through the membrane). The [Nuclear pore complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_pore#Import_of_proteins) is a good example of a machinery that allows larger folded proteins through the membrane.

Comment: For now, I am going to suggest that your question should be closed because I think it needs a bit more focus to fit the shorter answer Q&A style of this site, but if you have any specific questions along the way, please post a new question or edit this question. I hope that helps :)